# How to find and print out of a specific value from a list (at least i think thats what i want to do?)

Tags: python

```
if n == 0:
    print('And your products are: ')
    for i in inputs:
        with open('items.txt') as f: 
            for line in f:
                if i in line:
                    desc1 = line[9:17]
                    price1 = line[21:25]
                    print(str(desc1) + ' ' +str(price1) + ' ' + str(quantities))
```

There is no error when running the code. When run, it outputs:

```
Our available products are:
15372185 ChocBisc
13281038 AppJuice
26419633 TomaSoup
74283187 SprRolls
Enter the product code: 74283187
SprRolls
Price = 0.90
Available Quantity = 86
Is this what you want? (Y/N) y
How much would you like? 34
Would you like to continue? (Y/N) y
Continuing!
Enter the product code: 15372185
ChocBisc
Price = 1.20
Available Quantity = 50
Is this what you want? (Y/N) y
How much would you like? 45
Would you like to continue? (Y/N) n
System Closing!
And your products are: 
SprRolls 0.90 [34, 45]
ChocBisc 1.20 [34, 45]
```

As you can see, right at the bottom, it prints both quantities entered. I knew it was going to do this but i dont know how to rectify it. What i need it to do is to print only the quantity entered for that product code. Any help as always would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!!

Also i removed most of the script under while n == 1 since this is my coursework, and i would rather it didn't get copied or anything like that. Hopefully this still shows the relevant section of the code to the question.

Comment: Can you show us few lines of data in your 'items.txt' file? How is it formated

Comment: Sure. The text is as follows:   
    15372185 ChocBisc 50 1.20  
    13281038 AppJuice 67 1.50  
    26419633 TomaSoup 32 2.10  
    74283187 SprRolls 86 0.90

Each product has its own line, and the line ends in the decimal number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would re-write the latter part of your code to iterate through the *[range](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range)* of values in `inputs`, rather than the values themselves.  Then, you can call the index of the element you want to print from `quantities`.

As a caveat, this works in your case because the user send inputs to `inputs` one at a time (so, the indices of `inputs` correspond with the indices of `quantities`).  You might consider a different data structure to use within this code, like a *[dictionary](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)*, which could store product codes and quantities as key/value pairs.  Then, you can simply refer to the key of the dictionary when printing.

Here is how I would suggest changing your code:

```
if n == 0:
    print('And your products are: ')
    for i in range(len(inputs)):
        with open('items.txt') as f: 
            for line in f:
                if inputs[i] in line:
                    desc1 = line[9:17]
                    price1 = line[21:25]
                    print(str(desc1) + ' ' +str(price1) + ' ' + str(quantities[i]))
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Could you tell me how it works (as simply as possible i'm quite new to python).

Comment: No problem - the `range()` function in Python gives you integers in a sequence, like: range(5) = 0,1,2,3,4.  `len()` gives you the length (or size) of your list.  Basically, with `range(len(yourList))` you are iterating through the indices of your list, rather than the actual elements themselves (so `inputs[0]` is the 1st element of `inputs`, `inputs[1]` is the 2nd, and so on).  This way, you can use `i` to refer to the indices of `inputs`, and also the indices of `quantities` :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate). For example:

```
for index, i in enumerate(inputs):
  print(index, i)
```

That should print out

```
0, 74283187
1, 15372185
```

Getting the quantities is trivial: `quantities[index]`

Answer (score 0):

You're creating a new list for the quantities so at the end where you print out this list you can append it to print out only the product code of that item. Understand? I'll post the code in a little bit if I can.